# Rx<User>() missing argument - Flutter / GetX

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-getx

While using a GetxController on a class, and using Rx to get a FirebaseUser, I'm being shown an error, that I'm missing a positional argument

```dart
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Rx<User> _firebaseUser = Rx<User>();
  User get user => _firebaseUser.value;
```

Here on this **Rx<User>()** which is from package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart, I get the error :

*1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.dartnot_enough_positional_arguments*

After launching the emulator, I get this more detailed error :

*lib/core/controllers/auth_controller.dart:9:36: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
Rx _firebaseUser = Rx();*

*../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.1.3/lib/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_impl.dart:324:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Rx(T initial) : super(initial);*

I can't find what I'm supposed to add here, and every tutorial I saw, didn't specify any argument here.
Anyone knows the problem ?

Answer (score 24):

If you run with null safety, try it

```
 Rxn<User> firebaseUser = Rxn<User>();
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/get/latest/get_rx/get_rx-library.html

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with how you're creating a custom observable object. If you check out the [GetX docs](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md), this is the suggested way to do what you're doing. Search for "model" on that page.

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final firebaseUser = User().obs;
}
```

Also be aware that using getters and setter here is of no value. [See this link for an explanation as to why](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_getters_setters.html)

If that doesn't fix it, then try sharing your `User` class, and the rest of the Getx class, and how you're trying to access the `firebaseUser` from outside.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing this issue but i changed getx package to 3.26.0  solved the issue